# Unix cat and zip together

Tags: command-line, shell, unix

What I'm trying to do seems simple enough, but I can't get it to work, nor can I find anything on Google referring to how to do this?

I want to first cat a bunch of files, then zip the resulting file up, but in one command, not two.

I have a bunch of files with names like this:

```
File202112.txt
File202201.txt
File202202.txt
File202203.txt
...
File202212.txt
File202301.txt
```

I just want to cat together one year's worth, then zip the result.

So if I do this it works, but it's two commands:

```
cat File2022*.txt > All_2022.txt
zip All_2022.zip All_2022.txt
```

But I'm trying to combine them into one line using pipe, but when I do that it doesn't work:

```
cat File2022*.txt | zip All_2022.zip
zip error: Nothing to do!
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
[zip(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) :

> zip also accepts a single dash ("-") as the name of a file to be
> compressed, in which case it will read the file from standard input,
> allowing zip to take input from another program. For example:
>
> ```
> tar cf - . | zip backup -
> ```
>
> would compress the output of the tar command for the purpose of
> backing up the current directory. This generally produces better
> compression than the previous example using the -r option because zip
> can take advantage of redundancy between files. The backup can be
> restored using the command
>
> ```
> unzip -p backup | tar xf -
> ```

So in your case this will be :

```
cat File2022*.txt | zip All_2022.zip -
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you really want but you can do this.

```
mkfifo zip.pipe                   # create fifo
cat File2022*.txt > zip.pipe &    # pipe data to fifo, in background
zip --fifo All_2022.zip zip.pipe  # note the `--fifo` argument to zip
rm zip.pipe                       # cleanup
```

This *should* work but I have not tested it. When you unzip the archive you will have lost all file names and will just have a single stream of data.

Stolen shamelessly from an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956087/stdin-into-zip-command-how-do-i-specify-a-file-name)

Comment: I have 2 commands that I'm trying to reduce to 1 command.  Your solution ADDS more commands.  That is the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it adds complexity but it saves on disk space. You can also put them on a single line (as you wanted in your post) or have a shell script that combines everything into a single command. That said, the answer by @harrymc is a better solution.